# jQuery Autosuggest and PHP/MySQL issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm trying to populate an input field, using PHP/MySQL, with the Drew Wilson's jQuery Autosuggest plugin found here: http://tips4php.net/2010/09/ajax-autocomplete-with-jquery-and-php/

I get this error: **Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource on line 21**

Here is my code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$counter='0';
echo "{";
echo "query:'$query',";
echo "suggestions:[";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT airport, code FROM iata_airport_codes where name like '$query%' ORDER BY airport desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 1) {
        echo ",";
    }

    $airport=$row["airport"];
    $code=$row["code"];

    echo "'$airport', ('$code')";
}
echo "],}";

mysql_close($con);
```

What am I missing here? Can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of `$query`, also look up SQL injection and escaping inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource on line 21`

Always means that there is an error in your SQL query. Try printing myqsl_error() contents.

And you should use `json_encode()` not print json by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It`s display  an error:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT airport, code FROM iata_airport_codes where name like '$query%' ORDER BY airport desc") or die(mysql_error());
```